# Proper usage of OCMock with Singleton

Tags: ios, objective-c, ocmock

I am wondering what the proper way to use singleton.
I have read the following [Mocking Singletons](https://twobitlabs.com/2011/02/mocking-singletons-with-ocmock/)
The post is old and for right now we are using `OCMock` with the help of `OCMPartialMock` for instance:

```
@interface ManagerVisitorTests : XCTestCase
@property (nonatomic) id partialManager;
@property (nonatomic) id partialHelper;

@end

@implementation ManagerVisitorTests

static NSString *const key = @"key"; 
- (void)initSDKWithoutVisitor {
    self.partialManager = OCMPartialMock([manager sharedManager]);
    NSDictionary *decodedAppkey = @{};
    OCMStub([self.partialManager methods:OCMOCK_ANY]).andReturn(decodedAppkey);
}

- (void)testInitNoVisitor {
    [self initSDKWithoutVisitor];
    [self.partialManager initSDKWithoutVisitor:key];
    XCTAssertFalse([manager sharedInstance].isInitCalled, @"called");
    //OR
    XCTAssertFalse([self.partialManager sharedInstance].isInitCalled, @"called");
    [self stopAllMocks];
}

- (void)stopAllMocks {
    [self.partialManager stopMocking];
    [self.partialHelper stopMocking];
    self.partialManager = nil;
    self.partialHelper  = nil;
}


@end
```

I must admit that I don't fully understand how the `OCMock` works under the hood but it seems that `OCMPartialMock` should do the work according to the docs *This means that calls using a reference to the real object, even including self in methods where the object calls itself, are also affected by stubs and expectations*

Please advice if its a good approach for the singleton case?

Comment: What are you trying to test here? I see you are stubbing a method named `method:` on the manager instance. But in the test you're calling a different method, namely `initSDKWithoutVisitor:` with an argument `key` that's not declared anywhere. It's also unclear what the class of the manager instance is. Last but not least, you mention a blog post about singleton mocking but the link leads me to a page about  
"Log userInfo, not localizedDescription, for CoreData errors".

Comment: I fixed the link and edited the code, I tried to obscure some methods names.
The stub guarantees proper execution of initSDKWithoutVisitor. My question isnt about this specific method but more about the proper usage of OCMock with Singelton, Is PartialMock a valid approach for mocking Singelton? or maybe a small example with a better approach, and a couple of sentences on how OCMock implements it (changing innovocation or swizzeling or subclassing)

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't get what you're trying to test. It looks like calling `initSDKWithoutVisitor:` is meant to have a side-effect, namly setting the `isInitCalled` property. That you can test without OCMock. Now, is it that the `initSDKWithoutVisitor:` method calls `methods:` on itself and you want to stub that to return an empty dictionary? If that's the case then, yes, this is the right approach. As a matter of style I would use the reference to the partical mock to set up stubs and verify, and use the reference to the real object otherwise.

Comment: Regarding the implementation, as mentioned in the documentation OCMock dynamically creates subclasses and sets the class of the mocked object to the subclass; one subclass per partial mock.

Comment: Does it also copies all the properties to the new subclass?
How does it affect the original class, (in terms of what happens on stopMocking)?
(I do see some crashes on stopMocking, and I can't figure out why)